# TypeScript: is not assignable to boolean or PromiseLike

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, react-native-firebase, typescript-types

I'm writing a React Native app using TypeScript?

I have written a function wrapper for functions from React Native Firebase like this:

```
export const checkPermissions = (): Promise<boolean> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase
      .messaging()
      .hasPermission()
      .then(enabled => {
        if (enabled) {
          return resolve(enabled);
        } else {
          return firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
        }
      });
  });
```

Now I get the following error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(enabled: boolean) => void | Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: boolean) => boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>'.
  Type 'void | Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're returning `firebase.messaging().requestPermission();` as a method and not its results, what you need to do is to connect those two promises like this:

```
export const checkPermissions = (): Promise<boolean> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase
            .messaging()
            .hasPermission()
            .then(enabled => {
                if (enabled) {
                    resolve(enabled);
                } else {
                    firebase.messaging().requestPermission()
                        .then(resolve)
                        .catch(reject);
                }
            }).catch(reject);
    });
}
```